# show a small inline delete button upon button press in ng-bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

My Current implementation of what I want is done using `ng-bootstrap` for `Angular4`.

#### Image

[image: non checked button]

As you can see I used the Check box button to display a response from the backend. If you click on the button the **x** button will be not be shown and it will also hide some other html elements below.

#### Upon clicked (checked)

[image: checked button]

I am actually looking to improve the layout, where I wish that the **x** button would somehow be spanned together for a *smooth* feeling.

I do not know of any components from **Bootstrap4.x** or `ng-bootstrap` itself that could do something.

Any design suggestions or improvements is what I am looking for.

#### code

```
<!-- Search Keywords go here -->
<div class="container" *ngIf="Output.length">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label class="col-form-label-lg"><b> Search History </b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" *ngFor="let keyword of Output; let cbIndex = index">
                    <label class="btn-primary" ngbButtonLabel>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               ngbButton
                               #kwCheck
                               (change)="cbInput= kwCheck.checked; hideKW(cbIndex)"
                        > {{keyword.kw}}
                    </label>
                    <span><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                              (click)="deleteKW(keyword.kw); $event.stopPropagation()"
                              [disabled]=kwCheck.checked
                              [hidden]="kwCheck.checked">&times;</button>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Output.length` is an array of JSON responses from the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, at least, two ways that you can do so.

1. Use `btn-group`. It is pretty well semantic also, except that you use `btn` class for the  input container which is a not button.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <label class="btn d-flex align-items-center bg-primary px-3 mb-0">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" id="customCheck1">
    <span class="px-1 mb-0" for="customCheck1">Check</span>
  </label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">&times;</button>
</div>
```

2. Use `input-group`. I prefer this approach because all of the classes have meaning.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group w-auto">
  <label class="d-flex align-items-center w-auto bg-primary  px-3 mb-0">
    <input type="checkbox" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    <span class="pl-2">Check</span>
  </label>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">&times;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Update

In order to hide the checkbox's `tick mark`, use `btn-group-toggle`. It is the same method that [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) does.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group w-auto ">
  <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 0;">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Check
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn-danger btn" id="basic-addon1">&times;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*As far as i know, there is no way to reset the `border` to zero.* So, you have to use custom CSS.*

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKOdJv?editors=1000

Comment: Do you know why I still see the checkbox square whereas in `ng-bootstrap`documentation doesnt have one.

Comment: @Shan-Desai I do not  get you. Could you explain it further?

Comment: I meant the checkbox button. The button in [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples) don't have a square checkbox in them. But your example and mine have the square checkbox in them.

Comment: Because it is [`absolutely` positioned](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons).  Do you want to hide it?

Comment: Updated the answer @Shan-Desai